# Python typehint for os.getenv causes downstream incompatible type errors

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

When using [`os.getenv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) to retrieve environment variables, the default behavior returns a type of `Optional[str]`. This is problematic as any downstream methods/functions that utilize these variables will likely be defined to accept a `str` type explicitly. **Is there an accepted usage to get around this issue or enforce the `str` return type?**

In the stub file definition for `getenv` in [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/os/__init__.pyi#L360-L365) you can find that `getenv` can have a return type of `Optional[str]` or `Union[str, T_]` depending on the usage of the `default` kwarg.

The four options I can see as yet are:

1. Define any downstream operations to accept `Optional[str]` types as arguments. This doesn't feel particularly right as a function/method may not be structured in a way that the `Optional` type makes sense. i.e. the operation has no reason for a particular argument to be `None`.
2. Use the `default` kwarg for `getenv` and provide a `str` default value. This seems more correct, but requires that one set a default value for every usage of `getenv`. The only problem I can see with this is that doing so may be confounding for testing or usage in different environments.
3. Define some kind of variable checking function. This could be a function that accepts the name of an environment variable to load, explicitly returns a string, and raises an error if the environment variable doesn't exist.
4. Explicitly set the type of the value returned by `getenv` to be a str. I really don't like this as it expects the environment to always be properly configured which, in my experience, is not a good assumption.

Find below an example that raises a mypy error.

```py
import os

SOME_VAR = os.getenv("SOME_VAR")


def some_func(val: str) -> None:
    print(f"Loaded env var: {val}")


some_func(SOME_VAR)
```

The above raises the mypy error:

> error: Argument 1 to "some_func" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "str"

Comment: re: "Explicitly set the type of the value returned by getenv to be a str. I really don't like this as it expects the environment to always be properly configured which, in my experience, is not a good assumption." If this is the case, why would you use a str for some_func, if you accept something else than ```str```?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `os.environ['SOME_VAR']` if you're sure it's always there

---

`os.getenv` can and does return `None` -- mypy is being helpful in showing you have a bug there:

```
>>> repr(os.getenv('DOES_NOT_EXIST'))
'None'
>>> repr(os.getenv('USER'))
"'asottile'"
```

Alternatively, you can *convince* mypy that it is of the type you expect in two different ways:

1. utilizing assertions:

```py
x = os.getenv('SOME_VAR')
assert x is not None, x
# mypy will believe that it is non-None after this point
```

2. utilizing a cast:

   ```py
   from typing import cast

   x = cast(str, os.getenv('SOME_VAR'))
   # mypy will believe that it is a `str` after this point
   ```

(the cast has some downsides in that it is never checked, whereas the assertion will hopefully lead to a test failure)

I would suggest *not* ignoring this error / working around it and instead use `os.environ['SOME_VAR']` for things you expect to always be there, or write a condition to check for the error case when it is missing

Comment: This makes the most sense to me. I think I got hung up on `getenv` as I have been working with dot_env files and didn't even think of `environ`. I much prefer the fail fast approach that allows too.

Answer (score 0):

`SOME_VAR` is an optional because it can be `None`

> Return the value of the environment variable varname if it exists, or value if it doesn’t. value defaults to None.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getenv)

You could set a fallback if the environment variable doesn't exist:

```py
import os

SOME_VAR = os.getenv("SOME_VAR", "my fallback value")


def some_func(val: str) -> None:
    print(f"Loaded env var: {val}")

some_func(SOME_VAR)
```

This schould make `SOME_VAR` "not optional"